# Is it possible to change redirect without applying for a new app? Soundcloud API

Tags: node.js, api, redirect, soundcloud

I have an app already registered with Soundcloud, I just need to change the redirect URI to include a port number to use with node.js. Do I need to register a new app or can someone from the Soundcloud team help me?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in their documentation, you still have to contact Soundcloud. Try to request a new app, use the same information as before, but use your new redirect URI. In your description state that the app already exists, but you only need the `redirect_uri` changed.